# Irreducible Polynomial as Characteristic polynomial of a Matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, irreducible-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Given an irreducible polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{R}[X]$, does there exists an $n\times n $ real matrix with $p$ as its characteristics polynomial.

Since similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. The set $P_p:=\{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})\ | \chi_{A}=p\}$ is closed under conjugation. Then P can be written as a union of disjoint conjugacy classes (of similar matrices). **The question is how many conjugacy classes?**

---

I have a partial answer to this question. If $\ p=x^2+x+1$ then their are $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with characteristic polynomial $p$, where $tr(A)=-1\ $ and $\ det(A)=1$ so
$$A=\left( \begin{matrix} 
           -1  & 1 \\
           -1  & 0 
            \end{matrix}
     \right)$$
has $\chi_A= x^2+x+1$.
But I do not know how many conjugacy classes is the set $P_{x^2+x+1}$ composed of?

Comment: For the first question, see [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Comment: For the second, there is a "real Jordan form".  In particular, for an irreducible characteristic polynomial there is just one conjugacy class.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865620/n-times-n-real-matrix-with-characteristic-polynomial-p-where-p-is-an-irre?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually that question was posted by me. But that question had no complete answer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Can you please help me understand how there is just one conjugacy class?